# AMP pagination and filter in amp-form

Tags: amp-html

I want to create a search form in an AMP page the form and display returned data is working fine, but I wanted to know how to add

1. load more button
2. filter popup

I tried following implementations but didn't workout

1. added form inside the `submit-success` element but it generates errors
2. added `<amp-list>` but cannot use the `POST` method with `GET` method also I am not able to append data with some pagination.
3. tried to submit form externally using tap event but no use

any help would be appreciated